# Using get() in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a loop in R so that it runs through two vectors in R and look for non-factor vector and randomly select a number from the vector to replace the NA data.

e.g.

```
gender<-c("male","female","female","male",NA)    ## variable 1
gender<-as.factor(gender)  ## set gender as a factor
age<-c(11.4,13.7,45.6,24, NA)  ## variable 2

vector<-c("gender","age")
total<-2   ##number of variable is 2

for (i in 1:total)
{
 if (is.factor(get(vector[i]))==TRUE)  {print("This is a factor vector")}

 if (is.factor(get(vector[i]))==FALSE)
 {
  get(vector[i])[is.na(get(vector[i]))]<-
  sample(get(vector[i])[!is.na(get(vector[i]))],sum(is.na(get(vector[i])),replace=F))

 }
}
```

When I run this it says "could not find function "get<-".  I am not sure what the problem is...

Comment: `get`'s friend is `assign`. But shouldn't these things be in a data frame? It would make life easier.

Comment: @Spacedman how would putting these in a dataframe make it easier? Could you give any example?  Replacing 'get' with 'assign' produces another error "argument "value" is missing, with no default".  Is there something wrong with my code?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function that does the na-replacement. I've put `replace=TRUE` because if you've got more things to replace than there are in the vector then it will fail if `replace=FALSE`.  But if you're sure you want that then change `TRUE` to `FALSE`:

```
na.sample = 
function(x){miss=is.na(x);x[miss]=sample(x[!miss],sum(miss),TRUE);x}
```

note how this is a nice simple function you can test outside your loop:

```
> na.sample(c(1,2,3,4,NA,4,3))
[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 3
> na.sample(c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA,NA))
[1] 1 2 3 4 4 1 1
> na.sample(c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
> na.sample(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Obviously the last one fails because there's nothing left to replace it.

So your problem. If you really want to loop over variable names, which is a *bad thing*, use assign and get. I'll just show how to do it for one variable name, your loop should work:

```
> age
[1] 11.4 13.7 45.6 24.0   NA
> assign("age", na.sample(get("age")))
> age
[1] 11.4 13.7 45.6 24.0 11.4
```

But if you put them in a data frame. Assuming you have five records of age and gender, then these things should go in a data frame:

```
> d = data.frame(age=age, gender=gender)
> d
   age gender
1 11.4   male
2 13.7 female
3 45.6 female
4   NA   <NA>
5 11.4   male
```

Then loop over column names for the replacement. Here's one:

```
> d[["age"]] = na.sample(d[["age"]])
> d
   age gender
1 11.4   male
2 13.7 female
3 45.6 female
4 45.6   <NA>
5 11.4   male
```

Just do `for(name in c("age","gender")){ d[[name]]=na.sample(d[[name]])}` to replace all of them. Neat isn't it?

Comment: Thank you SO much!!  Just one more question, in the function you wrote, why when I leave out `;x}` the function no longer works?

Comment: A function returns the last thing it evaluates. I could have done `return(x)` but just having `x` as the last thing evaluated works too. EG: `foo=function(x){print("hello");x^2}` returns x squared same as `foo=function(x){print("hello");return(x^2)}`. Basic R function-writing stuff!